# Is it possible to record user touch/fling event on same controller in android by modifying android framework code?

Tags: android

I want to develop a tools to automatically record ui and ui2ui path during tester testing android app.

I plan to do screenshot when user do something on app.
so I want to know when user touch / fling on the screen.
Is it possible to record user touch/fling event on controllers in android by modifying android framework code?

Comment: Are you planning on building your own custom Android device, or your own custom build of the OS?

Comment: No, I just want to visualize the whole u testing process by graphic

Comment: If you are not building your own custom Android device or your own custom build of the OS, you cannot modify Android framework code.

Comment: I can modify framework codes by building custom OS, so how can I record user touch/fling events?

Comment: I find by statsd , I can get interaction events easily